# How to remove div tag content?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the content of a div tag using JavaScript?

I have tried some code, but it only removes the `level1` div (and of course all o it childern), but how can I remove only the content in `level3` inside?

```js
function destroyDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById("level1");
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="level1">

  <div id="level2">

    <div id="level3">
      <label> Test content </label>
    </div>

  </div </div>

  <div id=blahDiv>Remove me</div>
  <input type=button value='Remove the div' onclick='destroyDiv()'>
```

Comment: You want to remove the div itself or the content inside the opening and closing tags of a particular div is not clear from your post.

Comment: I guess you have got quite a few answers and almost unanimous and correct.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This sould work `document.getElementById("level3").innerHTML = '';` but try thinking about using jQuery, because `.innerHTML` implementation differs in some browsers. jQuery would look like `$('#level3').html('');`

Comment: @holian: then why question is tagged javascript? and what about this: ***how can i remove the content of a div tag with javascript***?

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you access directly `level3` ?

```
   document.getElementById("level3").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("level3").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var div = document.getElementById("level3");
div.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(() => { 
          'use strict';
          let needle = 'level3';
          if ( needle === '' || needle === '{{1}}' ) {
              needle = '.?';
          } else if ( needle.slice(0,1) === '/' && needle.slice(-1) === '/' ) {
              needle = needle.slice(1,-1);
          } else {
              needle = needle.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
          }
          needle = new RegExp(needle);
          const divnode = ev => {
                                        if (ev) { window.removeEventListener(ev.type, divnode, true); }
                                    try {
                                            const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
                                            for (const div of divs) {
                                                    if (div.outerHTML.match(needle)) {
                                                                    div.remove();
                                                    }           
                                            }
                                    } catch(ex) {
                                        }
          };
          if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
                   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', divnode, true);
          } else {
                   divnode();
          }
})();
```

There you go. A dedicated div-remover with RegEx support.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the `innerHTML` property to `""` works, a more DOM-ish solution to remove all of the content of a div is to use [replaceChildren](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren):

```
div.replaceChildren()
```